# How do I repair warping, creasing, and lamination separation on a paperback's covers?

Tags: physical-books

I just purchased a new paperback, shipped from China. Unfortunately, it made the journey in only a layer of bubble wrap and a plastic-bag mailer, so it arrived damaged: the whole book has a wave warped into it, and there is heavy denting/creasing on both covers and the spine, to the point that the plastic-laminate coating of the cover has separated from the paper in those areas. Never having dealt with any damage like this, I haven't tried anything yet for fear of making it worse. How do I repair, or at least minimize, this mess?

[image: Front cover]
[image: back cover]
[image: spine][image: warping]

Comment: Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange, take our [tour]! Delightful first question, hopefully you get a useful answer!

Comment: Related https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/15174/6973